# If we perform any updates or ddl statements in view will it refelect in the original database table from where the view has been created?

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have been asked this question in an interview can anyone explain?

If we perform any updates or ddl statements in view will it reflect in the original database table from where the view has been created?

Thanks

Comment: DDL is used to create or modify the view ("create view ..."). & It is possible to create an "updateable view" see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-updatability.html but I'm unclear what you are "updating". Are you changing the view SQL, or changing the data (update/insert). Please re-consider how you have worded this question, it is unclear what you are actually asking.

Comment: Is the VIEW an UPDATE?  And did you mean DML (data MODIFICATION)?

Comment: Sorry I just wanted to know if we can do any ddl operation on view, i think I have updated the question wrongly.